# Porque não volta nenhum resultado no PDO fetch collum?

Tags: php, pdo

Fiz uma query e quero usar o fetch collum de acordo com uma resposta do outro site;

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT b.**, b.**, b.**, b.**, b.**, b.**, b.**, b.**, b.**, b.**, b.token FROM tbl_contas AS b");
    $query->execute();

$iToken = $query->fetchColumn(11);
$tokenHash = $iToken['token'];
```

Porque não retorna o token na variavel `$tokenHash`?

Comment: `if(!$query->execute()){print_r($query->errorInfo());}` assim mostra algum erro?

Comment: Nenhum erro, tudo certo

Comment: Na sua consulta real tem aqueles dois asteriscos seguidos mesmo?

Comment: Não, foi só para ilustrar as posições @rray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está no índice da coluna ao total são 11 porém como a documentação informa a contagem deve começar em zero.

> 0-indexed number of the column you wish to retrieve from the row. If no value is supplied, PDOStatement::fetchColumn() fetches the first column.

Logo no seu caso mude:

```
$iToken = $query->fetchColumn(11);
```

Para:

```
$iToken = $query->fetchColumn(10);
```

**Leitura recomendada:**

[Documentação - fetchColumn()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)